# C lang "filter map" implementation with free

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, memory-management, linked-list

I'm trying to write very simple function that updates elements of linked list in place while filtering out (and freeing) some of the elements. I've been able to derive this implementation though according to valgrind it contains invalid free as well as memory leak. I wonder what is wrong with the implementation.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct List {
  int head;
  struct List *tail;
} List;

List *cons(int h, List *tail)
{
  List *list = malloc(sizeof(List));
  list->head = h;
  list->tail = (struct List*) tail;

  return list;
}

bool is_odd(int val)
{
  return val % 2 != 0;
}

int square(int val)
{
  return val * val;
}

void print_list(List *l)
{
  while (l) {
    printf("item: %d, ", l->head);
    l = (List*) l->tail;
  }

  printf("\n");
}

List *square_odd(List *list)
{
  List *new_head = NULL;
  List *prev_head = NULL;

  while (list != NULL) {
    List *next = (List *) list->tail;
    if (is_odd(list->head)) {
      if (new_head == NULL) new_head = list;
      if (prev_head != NULL) prev_head->tail = (struct List*) list;
      list->head = square(list->head);
      prev_head = list;
    } else {
      if (next == NULL) {
        prev_head->tail = NULL;
      }
      free(list);
    }

    list = next;
  }

  return new_head;
}

int main()
{
  List *t = NULL;
  List init = {100, NULL};
  t = &init;
  t = cons(1, t);
  t = cons(2, t);
  t = cons(3, t);
  t = cons(4, t);
  t = cons(5, t);
  t = cons(6, t);
  t = cons(7, t);
  t = cons(8, t);

  t = square_odd(t);

  List *tmp = NULL;
  print_list(t);

  while(t->tail != NULL) {
    tmp = t;
    t = (List*) t->tail;
    if (tmp != NULL) free(tmp);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

valgrind output is:

```
==17692== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==17692== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==17692== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==17692== Command: ./main
==17692== 
==17692== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==17692==    at 0x4835948: free (in /nix/store/wrj8cjkfqzi0qlwnigx8vxwyyfl01lqq-valgrind-3.15.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17692==    by 0x40127D: square_odd (in /tmp/linked/main)
==17692==    by 0x401371: main (in /tmp/linked/main)
==17692==  Address 0x1ffeffeac0 is on thread 1's stack
==17692==  in frame #2, created by main (???:)
==17692== 
item: 49, item: 25, item: 9, item: 1, 
==17692== 
==17692== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17692==     in use at exit: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==17692==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 9 frees, 1,152 bytes allocated
==17692== 
==17692== LEAK SUMMARY:
==17692==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==17692==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17692==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17692==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17692==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17692== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==17692== 
==17692== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==17692== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to share what valgrind has found.

Comment: @Marek Fajkus At least use normal names instead of these silly names of data members   typedef struct List {
  int head;
  struct List *tail;
} List;

Comment: You don't need the typecast in `t = (List *)t->tail;`. It's already the correct type.

Comment: `square_odd` doesn't update elements in place, it creates new elements. Why?

Comment: @vlad `car` and `cdr`?

Comment: @~kaylum valgrind output added, thanks for good point.

@~VladfromMoscow not sure how much is that relevant. I guess for hc lisp guy car and cdr might be better as @Antti Haapala says but I'm not sure if that's what you mean.

@~Barmar I'm not sure what makes you concern about in place update. the square function is pure function returning new int indeed but the update of list structure happesn in place as far as I can tell.

Comment: You are freeing `&init`, it wasn't allocated by malloc.

Comment: thanks @KamilCuk you're right of course. This solves the invalid free. When fixing this there is still 16bytes leak (one malloc that is not freed) which indicates off by one error. Pls post this as a aswer so I can approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is wrong with the implementation.

You are passing the address of `init` to `free`. `init` is a variable with auto storage duration not allocated with `malloc`, so you can't `free` it.

Because initially `t = &init`, then inside the first call to `cons` you do `new_t->tail = t` you effectively do `new_t->tail = &init`. So after all the `cons` calls the last element in your chain points to `&init`.

```
 t->tail-> ... ->tail->tail == &init
```

Inside your loop then you pass address of `&init` to the `free` function.

I would say the implementation is actually ok, the allocation of the first element is wrong.

I suggest, just remove the `init` and create the first chain with `malloc` too:

```
int main() {
   List *t = cons(100, NULL);
   t = cons(1, t);
   // the rest unchanged
```

`free(NULL)` does nothing. You can replace `if (tmp != NULL) free(tmp);` with just `free(tmp)`.

Comment: I've approved the answer as it indeed resolved the main thing that I missed which  which was the free of the value allocated on stack within the main. Though even with these chages the vagrind still reports there is an leak of 16bytes. if you can spot the error @KamilCuk please let me know. Otherwise I still consider this to be the right answer given it resolves the major issue.